# Converting an XML document to CSV with both its attributes and data through XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

I wonder how can I convert an XML document to CSV format regarding its attribute values through using XSLT?

Thanks in advance.

This is my XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

Starting from first child element all elements' values and their attributes if they have need to be printed by seperating commas

Comment: Can you show the xslt that you have tried so far? I can help fix it, if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer by mhawke is good, it is not very flexible. For instance, if you want to normalize the space for the values (and I think you want that, because with your current input, the fields will span multiple lines, which is often not supported with CSV), you have to wrap each and every field. Also, if you introduce new fields, you will have to change the stylesheet.

Typically, in XSLT, you use templates, which makes it more flexible to extend and expand. The below stylesheet works with your input. I added the `normalize-space` function, the `xsl:strip-space` to get rid of irrelevant whitespace in your source document, and, of course, it outputs the attribute as well.

If you have multiple attributes, you can just as well do apply-templates on attributes as well to make that more flexible too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method='text'/>

    <xsl:template match="/">        
        <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog/book"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- matches a book-record -->
    <xsl:template match="book">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- matches any field (inside book record) -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
        <!-- use normalize-space, otherwise fields will span multiple lines -->
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>

        <!-- no comma after the last field -->
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With your input, it generates this output (note, I deliberately did not quote the ID value):

```
bk101,"Gambardella, Matthew","XML Developer's Guide","Computer","44.95","2000-10-01","An in-depth look at creating applications with XML."
bk102,"Ralls, Kim","Midnight Rain","Fantasy","5.95","2000-12-16","A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world."
bk103,"Corets, Eva","Maeve Ascendant","Fantasy","5.95","2000-11-17","After the collapse of a nanotechnology society in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new society."
bk104,"Corets, Eva","Oberon's Legacy","Fantasy","5.95","2001-03-10","In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve Ascendant."
bk105,"Corets, Eva","The Sundered Grail","Fantasy","5.95","2001-09-10","The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, battle one another for control of England. Sequel to Oberon's Legacy."
bk106,"Randall, Cynthia","Lover Birds","Romance","4.95","2000-09-02","When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled."
bk107,"Thurman, Paula","Splish Splash","Romance","4.95","2000-11-02","A deep sea diver finds true love twenty thousand leagues beneath the sea."
bk108,"Knorr, Stefan","Creepy Crawlies","Horror","4.95","2000-12-06","An anthology of horror stories about roaches, centipedes, scorpions and other insects."
bk109,"Kress, Peter","Paradox Lost","Science Fiction","6.95","2000-11-02","After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems of being quantum."
bk110,"O'Brien, Tim","Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible","Computer","36.95","2000-12-09","Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in detail in this deep programmer's reference."
bk111,"O'Brien, Tim","MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide","Computer","36.95","2000-12-01","The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, SAX and more."
bk112,"Galos, Mike","Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide","Computer","49.95","2001-04-16","Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth, looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are integrated into a comprehensive development environment."
```

And, as an alternative to the above solution, you can consider to *only* quote those fields that actually need quoting (because they have a comma in them). This example also shows why it is so trivial to expand when you use template based processing (which is what XSLT is all about):

Just replace the last template with these two templates:

```
<!-- with a comma in the field, quote it -->
<xsl:template match="*[contains(text(), ',')]">
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    <!-- use normalize-space, otherwise fields will span multiple lines -->
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
    <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>

    <!-- no comma after the last field -->
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<!-- without a comma -->
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

The first line of output now looks like this (note the deliberately missing quotes around the 3rd etc fields):

```
bk101,"Gambardella, Matthew",XML Developer's Guide,Computer,44.95,2000-10-01,An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access attribute values using "@attribute" in a `xsl:value-of`, e.g.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
```

Because you are generating CSV you need to consider that your data contains commas (e.g. in the `<author>, <title>` and `<description>` tags), and that you need to quote these fields. Alternatively you could choose to use a different delimiter character that can not appear in your data. Some info on quoting etc is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

And here is a XSL stylesheet that does what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method='text'/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="catalog/book">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>,"<xsl:value-of select="author"/>","<xsl:value-of select="title"/>",<xsl:value-of select="genre"/>,<xsl:value-of select="price"/>,<xsl:value-of select="publish_date"/>,"<xsl:value-of select="description"/>"

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```